# Why Cassandra client is slower in ec2 then a machine out of aws?

Tags: amazon-ec2, cassandra

I have set up a 6 nodes cluster in ec2. I tried to scan a table with 100M rows--2000 partitions. I wrote a client with launching 20-50 threads to read the table by 
for partitionkey in keys
select * from table where partitionkey=?

Each query is a task executed by a thread. When I ran my application in my mac, it is 2x faster then it is running a m3.2xlarge box in ec2.

I also noticed that when I run the application in my mac, traffic is kind of distributed evenly to 6 nodes. However, when my application is running on ec2, nearly half traffic goes to one node. I tried to set pool options to limit connections to one host, it did not help.

Any one has ideal? Thanks in advance.

Comment: For folks to be able to help you you're going to have to add some details on your application. What driver are you using, are you using a token aware routing policy in that driver?

Comment: I am using cassandra-driver-core 2.1.5. My table is pretty simple create table (time_id, ...)primary key(timeid, one). I created a Cluster[], each element is a cluster contacting one node of the cluster.

Answer (score 0):

I set broadcast_rpc_address as a public ip, can client in aws using private IP.